# Forgotten administrative password

Tags: password-recovery

I have forgotten the administrative password on my laptop. I have tried booting into recovery mode as suggested but I don't get the menu where I can use the cursors to select recovery mode. All I get is a line of writing sayingS:

```
gnu grub version 2.02 beta2-36ubuntu3.14
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you forget your root user password or your not root admin user password?

Comment: It's the root user password iv forgotten

Comment: GRUB is the bootloader, not a shell. It's where you select Recovery Console from early in the boot process. If your GRUB options are not loading, then your root password is irrelevant and this entire question is misleading - you have a GRUB problem, not a lost password problem. You may also have a separate lost password problem, but that does not matter until you fix or reinstall GRUB.

Comment: Since you seem to be a rather new user, ADVICE: 1) Boot from a LiveUSB. 2) Backup your data. 3) Reinstall Ubuntu. Next time, don't enable root. Use Ubuntu the way it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember your admin user password You could login as a root user without knowing root user password using:

Open terminal and input the next:

- `sudo - su`

or

- `sudo -i`

When logged in as root with one of the above commands, you could change its password by command:

```
passwd
```

Admin user, but not root means that this user is a member of `sudo` group and could execute privileged commands using its own password, not root's.

Comment: You will have to forgive me I'm not very computer savvy how do I do what you have just suggested

Comment: Open terminal and enter one of those commands: `sudo su` for example. You will get root's terminal access. Being there you could change your root user's password by executing `passwd` command.

Comment: I dont remember my administrative password

Comment: It's your usual user password you input when starting your system, except if you configured autologin. How do you login into your system?

Comment: I cant I dont remember the password I can only login as a guest.